# Interface that extends either of two interfaces and adds some properties?

Tags: typescript

`Action` should have the properties `children`, `size?` and `variant?`.

`Action` should also implement either of `Button` or `Link`.

How can I achieve this?

Here is my best attempt

```
interface Button {
    action: () => void;
    href?: never;
}
interface Link {
    href: string;
    action?: never;
}

interface Action extends Button | Link {
    children: string;
    size?: 'large' | 'small';
    variant?: 'secondary';
}
```

Error:

```
[tslint] Forbidden bitwise operation
```

The functional requirement I really have is that I want to create a type or interface that has some props plus either `action` or `href`, but not both `action` and `href`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An interface can't extends a union type unfortunately. You could use an intersection type instead:

```
interface Button {
    action: () => void;
    href?: never;
}
interface Link {
    href: string;
    action?: never;
}

type Action =  (Button | Link) & {
    children: string;
    size?: 'large' | 'small';
    variant?: 'secondary';
}

let a: Action = {
    href: "",
    children: "",
    size: "large"
}


let a2: Action = {
    action: () => { },
    children: "",
    size: "large"
}


let a3: Action = { // error
    href: ""
    action: () => { },
    children: "",
    size: "large"
}
```